# Cannot install some packages from npm

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, npm-install

My computer has a strange problem. Whenever I try to install some npm packages like ionic and cordova, it fails giving some shasum check failed error.
Like this cmd snapshot:

[image]

This has happened with other packages like generator-ionic

I've also checked for proxy setups in `Internet Options` and `Router Settings`, there are none.

Also, when I try to install these packages using my phone's data connection (usb tethering) they get installed without any problems.

I am assuming there is some problem with my internet connection, but can't seem to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your network is blocking the npm repository ,You may get this error ,Please use fiddler to debug you npm is able to connect to repository

Comment: I have downloaded fiddler web debugger, what do I do now?